# Is it possible to refer a manifest file from another manifest file in OSGI bundle?

Tags: java, osgi, manifest, aem

We have a requirement of merging two manifest file and i am trying to avoid that.
so is it possible to refer a manifest within a manifest?

Comment: Merging of two manifest files should have a goal. What is yours?

Answer (score 0):

No, manifest file format has no provision for referencing external files apart from signatures so your functionality which, if I understand correctly, is to include the contents of another manifest file into a manifest file by some form of reference cannot be achieved.